# In CakePHP, I can call a a dummy method in a model fine before auth call, but not after auth

Tags: cakephp

I get the error

> Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

My plugin is located in the common cake folder, outside of the app folder, so that multiple apps can use it.

**CakeFolder/plugins/myPlugin/Controller/UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    // This works
    public function dummySignin(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->dummyMethod(); //called before auth
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
            }
        }
    }

    // This doesn't
    public function signin(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->User->dummyMethod(); //called after auth
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CakeFolder/plugins/myPlugin/Model/User.php**

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function dummyMethod(){
        return true;
    }

}
```

I haven't declared the model name in the controller as it's loaded automagicly. Also, I have tried specifying the user model in the Auth component declaration without any result. It seems to be due to my model not being properly loaded, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Do you have a User model in the app that this plugin uses? If so, you'll need to declare your model explicitly in your plugin, using the plugin name as a prefix, ie `$this->User = ClassRegistry::init('PluginName.User');`

Comment: I get the same results with a blank app. I am also unable to load the plugin manually ( I tried your suggestion and also `loadModel()`). When I try output `debug($this->User)`. I get `object(User) {...}` before the auth call, and the result after the auth call is `object(AppModel) {...}` even though it's loaded manually right above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quote from my original post

> I have tried specifying the user model in the Auth component declaration without any result.

That's where I was wrong. It turns out that I had a mistake in my Auth setup. My custom model was declared outside of the authenticate option. Here's what I had:

```
'userModel' => 'myPlugin.User',
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
    )
),
```

While the correct usage is:

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'userModel' => 'myPlugin.User',
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
    )
),
```

Thank you all for the answers. That was a case of [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with the fact that Cake tries to use the User model in app/Models with the Auth component and it's getting confused between your plugins User model? Reading here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html the model that Auth uses by default is User, so maybe you could override that to use your plugin? Not sure if you have to explicitly state that considering the controller is within your plugin too...